# Autocomplete won't work with "If" statement

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete in my project, but I'm having some problems.

My autocomplete is working, but I want to add a permanent item in the last result of Autocomplete. For this, I'm using _renderItem (because I want use a different style for this item, centered, with a background-color: #000).

### Working code:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
      .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
      .append("<div style='text-align: center;'>" + item.label + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
}
```

As you can see, this apply this style to all items in the autocomplete. **So I updated my code to:**

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        if (item.type==="noneResult"){
            return $("<li></li>")
              .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
              .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
              .append("<div style='text-align: center;'>" + item.label + "</div>")        .appendTo(ul);
        }
 }
```

And here is where I populate my Autocomplete:

```
$.getJSON(
        '<%= my_rails_path %>.json',
        {search: term},
        function(json) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                var item = {};
                item.type = ' ';
                item.label = value.name;
                item.value = value.name;
                result.push(item);
            })

            var item = {};
            item.type = "noneResult";
            item.label = "Create a new book called '" + term + "'."; 
            item.value = term;
            result.push(item)

                response(result);
        }
);
```

If I use the "working code", everything's well, but all items are displayed centered. If I use the "updated code" in my project I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of undefined
```

So I want know, I'm making something wrong? Why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything for the general case. Only your specific case gets treated but the "normal" items come first and they are a dead end because then the function returns nothing.

So add a simple `else` for the default case:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  if (item.type==="noneResult"){
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
      .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
      .append("<div style='text-align: center;'>" + item.label + "</div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
  }
  else
  {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
      .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
      .append("<div style='text-align: center;'>" + item.label + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wooow, really thanks man! I'm trying for long time solve this issue. Take my best answer! Flying Spaghetti Monster bless you!